# MailMessage From vs Credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I'm trying to understand how From address is used in System.Net.Mail libraries.

For sake of argument I'm going to use google as an example.  Below you will find the code that I am using to send out the e-mail.

```
var message = new MailMessage();
message.To.Add(new MailAddress("john.doe@gmail.com"));  // replace with valid value 
message.From = new MailAddress("test@gmail.com");  // replace with valid value
message.Subject = "Testing ASP.NET Email system";
message.Body = "This is my test email";
message.IsBodyHtml = true;

using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
{
      var credential = new NetworkCredential
      {
           UserName = "test@gmail.com",  // replace with valid value
           Password = "abc123"  // replace with valid value
      };
      smtp.Credentials = credential;
      smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
      smtp.Port = 587;
      smtp.EnableSsl = true;
      await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
}
```

What I am trying to understand is why do I need to set From address and what is the point of it.  When you send an e-mail, should the e-mail credentials you logged in with be the From e-mail?  Would this mean I can log in as test@gmail.com but when recepient gets the e-mail it will say john@gmail.com if I put john as the From portion?

How does this works exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From is simply how your email client will display the from-email. As long as it's on the same (sub)domain as the *actual* mail server, most clients will allow it, otherwise you can get warnings such as this:

[image]

The reason you can send specify the from-address is because mail-servers do not necessarily have 'accounts' in the same way we do with hosted providers (gmail, hotmail, etc). The specifier before the `@` is simply a way for inboxes to be organised. For outgoing mail, it's not required from a technical standpoint, as the actual sender is your mail server, not your inbox.

Public mail servers will most likely prevent you from maliciously spoofing an address (ie, `dan@gmail.com` will probably have his request rejected if trying to send from `rob@gmail.com`) but the details about this I'm unsure of.

For example, here's a snippet from an email I received:

> Received: from mta.email.auspost.com.au (mta.email.auspost.com.au.
>   [207.67.38.247]) by mx.google.com with ESMTP id
>   qg3si8833298pbb.100.2015.11.18.19.17.54
>
> ...
>
> Received: by mta.email.auspost.com.au id h9kvm4163hs8 for
>   <==snip==@gmail.com>; Wed, 18 Nov 2015 21:01:47 -0600 (envelope-from
>   )
>   From: "Australia Post" <noreply@email.auspost.com.au>

(gmail example. source:
http://www.groovypost.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/image20.png)